Why is my MSBuild not renaming the extension?
  <Target Name="BackupAssemblies">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Assemblies Include="$(MyInputs)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="Backing: @(Assemblies) -> @(Assemblies -> Replace('.dll', '.bak'))" Importance="High" />
    <!--
    <Move SourceFiles="@(Assemblies)" DestinationFiles="@(Assemblies -> Replace('%(Extension)', '.bak'))" />
    -->
  </Target>

Using hardcoded string such as '.dll' worked but not when using the %(Extension)?
The following doesn't work.
<Message Text="Backing: @(Assemblies) -> @(Assemblies -> Replace('%(Extension)', '.bak'))" Importance="High" />

The test was done with the following command in the console:

msbuild .\Blah.csproj /t:BackupAssemblies /p:MyInputs=obj\Release\net8.0\WASDWASD.dll

Output:

Backing: obj\Release\net8.0\WASDWASD.dll -> obj\Release\net8.0\WASDWASD.dll

BTW, how could I pass an array of path through the command line? I want to test batch processing too.

You are using a transform but there is no Replace function within a transform. See the documentation on transforms. You could use <Move SourceFiles="@(Assemblies)" DestinationFiles="@(Assemblies->'%(rootdir)%(directory)%(filename).bak'" /> which, given obj\Release\net8.0\WASDWASD.dll, would rename the file to obj\Release\net8.0\WASDWASD.bak.

Multiple paths can be passed in one property by delimiting with a semi-colon. You need to allow for the syntax of the shell you are using. In a Windows cmd shell, enclose the semi-colons in a quoted string, e.g. /p:MyInputs="obj\Release\net8.0\WASDWASD.dll;bin\Release\net8.0\foo.dll".
